# Does Runtime.getRuntime().exec not work with .swf

Tags: java

I am making a program that starts a few programs when you click on a button.  I have run .exe files without a problem but when i try to run a .swf it gives me this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\\blah\\blah\\blah\\realm.swf": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at newbuttonthing.buttonthing$6.widgetSelected(buttonthing.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at newbuttonthing.buttonthing.open(buttonthing.java:48)
    at newbuttonthing.buttonthing.main(buttonthing.java:33)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
```

I am trying to run this:

```
Button Realm = new Button(shlStarter, SWT.NONE);
        Realm.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                try {
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                            "C:\\Users\\liam\\Desktop\\rotmg\\realm.swf");
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        Realm.setText("Realm");
        Realm.setBounds(308, 50, 116, 25);
```

Comment: `swf` is a data file, not an executable file.  You need to run the flash player.  You could try [`Desktop.open`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open(java.io.File)) instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .swf file is not an executable.  When you double click an .swf file, the Desktop manager uses the default registered program for swf files and passes this file as argument.  You can though recreate the behaviour using the windows START command. So try...

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("start C:\\Users\\liam\\Desktop\\rotmg\\realm.swf");
```

Or as pointed out by Mad Progarammer :)

```
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("C:\\Users\\liam\\Desktop\\rotmg\\realm.swf"));
}
```

Comment: Or [`Desktop.open`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open(java.io.File)) which may provide a platform indepdent solution